# In JIRA, how can we have separate boards/views for the PO and the team in the same sprint?

Tags: project-team, jira, product-owner, board

We don't want the stories to show up in our team's board because they don't work on the stories but rather on the tasks. At the same time our POs (We have a main PO and his delegate) don't want to see the tasks being worked on but rather only the progress of the stories.

The story/epic statuses and their workflow is different than the task/subtask statuses and their workflow.

I've tried to create a separate board for the POs but it includes the tasks, too. Maybe I couldn't find the correct way to filter out the tasks from this second board but this method is not the ideal way we want to handle this problem. We would like to have a single board which could be filtered out based on the logged in user's role.

Could you please point me to a suitable solution for this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [swimlanes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/glossary/swimlane) or [Quick Filters](https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile/glossary/quick-filter) to separate those views for your POs.

**Using Quick Filters:**

On your board page:

1. Go to Board->Configure
2. Select "Quick Filters"
3. Add a new Quick Filter with Query "Issuetype=Story"

On your board it will look like below:

> [image: config]
>   [image]

---

**Using Swimlanes:**

For swimlanes the query looks exactly the same.

1. Go to Board->Configure
2. Select "Swimlanes"
3. Add a new Swimlane with Query "Issuetype=Story"

> [image]

On the board there will be a division between Stories and other items:

> [image]

Comment: Many thanks Irina. The "Active Spring" board on my account doesn't have those "Stories" and "Everything Else" filters but after defining the swimlanes based on queries the stories and tasks have been separated into two layers so the result is the same and I don't have to use two different boards. Everything can be filtered on the same board.

Comment: I have a specific request which can't be realized with your method. I want to use different swimlane names for different swimlane queries and board filters. My POs use a workflow which has 7 steps and 5 swimlanes and my team uses a workflow with 5 steps and 4 different swimlanes. The process steps (swimlanes) are named differently. With your method I'm using a common swimlane where the POs see the correct amount of process steps on the board but not the correct step names and the team members do see the correct nomenclature for their process steps but not the correct amount of process steps.

Comment: for the case you described you need to create 2 different Scrum boards (for team and for POs) and decide which swimlanes are needed for each board.